# map two directive names to one directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive which is set using a class because most of the properties are related to that class.

The class is `resizable-sideways` or `resizable-updown`.

Right now, the directive is called resizable, and I then look for the element class name of either `resizable-sideways` or `resizable-updown`.

Is there some way to change

`angular.module('resizable',function()...`

and have it work with

`angular.module('resizable-sideways'||'resizable-updown',function()...`

Answer (score 0):

you can leave name as it is, it is poor idea have two different names for directive, you can use some attribute and watch his state, then use

```
element.addClass();
```

in your directive

Comment: I actually think it may be better usability for developers to have two names. I don't have a problem with adding a class, and I don't need to add a class, I just default it if they don't provide a `sideways` or `updown` class, it's more that I have a problem with muckying up my code with extra classes when they aren't needed. Particularly in angular apps where I now have 5 classes on certain divs, and I'm only just beginning.  I'm not concerned about the performance of having so many classes, it's just ugly to look at the code with so many classes.